# Did I implement this correctly?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, drawing

I'm trying to implement line thickness as denoted here:

```
start = line start = vector(x1, y1)
end = line end = vector(x2, y2)
dir = line direction = end - start = vector(x2-x1, y2-y1)
ndir = normalized direction = dir*1.0/length(dir)
perp = perpendicular to direction = vector(dir.x, -dir.y)
nperp = normalized perpendicular = perp*1.0/length(perp)

perpoffset = nperp*w*0.5
diroffset = ndir*w*0.5


p0, p1, p2, p3 = polygon points:
p0 = start + perpoffset - diroffset
p1 = start - perpoffset - diroffset
p2 = end + perpoffset + diroffset
p3 = end - perpoffset + diroffset
```

I have implemented this like this:

```
 void OGLENGINEFUNCTIONS::GenerateLinePoly(const std::vector<std::vector<GLdouble>> &input, std::vector<GLfloat> &output, int width)
 {
     output.clear();
     float temp;
     float dirlen;
     float perplen;
     POINTFLOAT start;
     POINTFLOAT end;
     POINTFLOAT dir;
     POINTFLOAT ndir;
     POINTFLOAT perp;
     POINTFLOAT nperp;

     POINTFLOAT perpoffset;
     POINTFLOAT diroffset;

     POINTFLOAT p0, p1, p2, p3;

     for(int i = 0; i < input.size() - 1; ++i)
     {
         start.x = input[i][0];
         start.y = input[i][1];

         end.x = input[i + 1][0];
         end.y = input[i + 1][1];

         dir.x = end.x - start.x;
         dir.y = end.y - start.y;

         dirlen = sqrt((dir.x * dir.x) + (dir.y * dir.y));

         ndir.x = dir.x * (1.0 / dirlen);
         ndir.y = dir.y * (1.0 / dirlen);

         perp.x = dir.x;
         perp.y = -dir.y;

         perplen = sqrt((perp.x * perp.x) + (perp.y * perp.y));

         nperp.x = perp.x * (1.0 / perplen);
         nperp.y = perp.y * (1.0 / perplen);

         perpoffset.x = nperp.x * width * 0.5;
         perpoffset.y = nperp.y * width * 0.5;

         diroffset.x = ndir.x * width * 0.5;
         diroffset.y = ndir.y * width * 0.5;

            // p0 = start + perpoffset - diroffset
             //p1 = start - perpoffset - diroffset
             //p2 = end + perpoffset + diroffset
            // p3 = end - perpoffset + diroffset 

         p0.x = start.x + perpoffset.x - diroffset.x;
         p0.y = start.y + perpoffset.y - diroffset.y;

         p1.x = start.x - perpoffset.x - diroffset.x;
         p1.y = start.y - perpoffset.y - diroffset.y;

         p2.x = end.x + perpoffset.x + diroffset.x;
         p2.y = end.y + perpoffset.y + diroffset.y;

         p3.x = end.x - perpoffset.x + diroffset.x;
         p3.y = end.y - perpoffset.y + diroffset.y;


         output.push_back(p0.x);
         output.push_back(p0.y);
         output.push_back(p1.x);
         output.push_back(p1.y);
         output.push_back(p2.x);
         output.push_back(p2.y);
         output.push_back(p3.x);
         output.push_back(p3.y);
     }


 }
```

but right now the lines look perpendicular and wrong; it should be giving me quads to render which is what I'm rendering, but the points it is outputting are strange. Have I done this wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I can tell you one thing you did wrong.  You've got the C++ equivalent of a "wall of text".  Consolidate some of that stuff into functions and/or objects.

Comment: There is one other problem.  Go back to the answer I gave you on your previous question where my function calculates nperp.  Notice how it handles the case where you would accidentally try to "negate" zero when calculating the perpendicular.  You need to check for this case.

Comment: Will a boolean answer suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating perp incorrectly. It should be `(y, -x)`, not `(x, -y)`. I don't know if that's the only bug. This one just jumped out at me.

As an aside, I strongly recommend that you define a useful vec2 type, with useful helpers like:

```
vec2 perp(vec2 v) { return vec2(v.y, -v.x); }
```

That way, your code will look almost the same as your pseudocode. Manipulating `x` and `y` individually is much more error-prone and harder to read. It is quite simple to build a basic class for this purpose, though you might be better off finding a third-party implementation to avoid mistakes like the above one. Most game/graphics/physics engines provide a bunch of useful types and functions.